# Is there a difference between export and export type for enums in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, enums, es6-modules

I have a simple enum which looks like this:

```
enum ConfigurationStatus {
  NotStarted,
  Complete
}

export default ConfigurationStatus;
```

Application is quite large so I use index files to simplify the exports. And when you use index file and re-export your interfaces it forces you to export them using `export type`. But when it comes to re-exporting enums it lets you do either simply `export` or `export type`. Here is an example of a part of my `index.ts` file:

```
export { default as ConfigurationStatus } from './ConfigurationStatus';
export type { default as IConfiguration } from './IConfiguration';
```

So is there any difference between `export` and `export type` for enums? Shoud I prefer one over another?